# Help understanding change of basis problem

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

[image]

So I'm struggeling with (ii). To be honest, I don't even understand what it means when the say that I'm supposed to assume that $\vec{u}$ in E-coordinates. And does the apostrophe mean that we are supposed to find the derivative? I'm really lost as one can see and I don't find anything in my book explaining this. Does someone have some tips or links a similar problem?

Edit: So I found a theorem in my book that might help after all:

$[x]_c=P_{c\leftarrow b}[x]_b$

So is this right then when it comes to my problem?

$\pmatrix{x'\\y'}$=$\pmatrix{cos\theta & sin\theta\\-sin\theta&cos\theta}\pmatrix{x\\y}$ where the $2\times 2$ matrix is the $P_{(\beta\leftarrow\epsilon)}$

$x'=xcos\theta+ysin\theta$

$y'=-xsin\theta+ycos\theta$

Comment: Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), as images are not searchable. Also, edits, or additional notes to your question should be placed within the original question itself.

Comment: @Laufen. Ok, I will add my answer below as a edit to my question and try to write it instead of adding the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So coordinate is coefficient of your basis.  I suppose x and y are coordinate. To get a concrete understanding , i recommand you to assume epsilon coordinate system to be e1=(1,0) e2=(0,1) and beta to be e'1=(1,1) e'2=(-1,1)  ex) u= x'e'1+ y'e'2 = (x'-y',x'+y') = (x,y) = xe1+ye2
now get abstract using your text book. coordinate change matrix

Comment: Ok, I will try that and come back to you and see if I get it right :)

Comment: After looking at your answer @JMK for some time I'm stuck on why beta is assumed to be e'1=(1,1) e'2=(-1,1). But I found a theorem in my book after all, and wonder if my solution is right and gives the same result as yours?

Comment: beta is just an example. In my example, since 2x'= x+y , 2y'=y-x  , matrix would be [1/2, 1/2  | -1/2 , 1/2] . beta is not a good example if you obsessed with 90 degree. Basis is just linearly independent vectors which spans the space. So you (ii) should be written as you introuduce P(beta <-> epsilon) matrix.(abtract). your rotation matrix  is too spectific.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I got my rotation matrix for (i) by the way, so thought I could use it in (ii). What do you mean by that the matrix is to specific?

Comment: Ok. I misunderstand it. I thought in (ii) that epsilon and beta are arbitrary. So if epsilon and beta are given as (i) then yes your answer is right.